# Xerox WorkCentre 3045 Scanner Driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: scanner, xerox

I have recently purchased this multifunction printer and installed the printer successfully through cups but the scanner is not getting detected. I have tried many alternatives with xsane but failed. Please help!!

Comment: You know what? Me too. It worked with 14.04, does not work with 16.04 anymore. The driver is proprietary and it seems we're all out of luck unless Xerox releases any update.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no scanner driver for WC 3045 on Linux at all... It only works as a printer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/714473)

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh if this information is correct, it's a completely valid answer

Comment: @Zanna I'd have added where did I find the information. and how to find it for yourself, but I think this can be debated

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh good point, I agree with you, the post author should provide a reference in these cases. Serge, how do you know this is correct?